# retrieve wordpress featured image (thumbnail) programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, thumbnails

HI I am using wordpress v3.03 and I am wondering how do I get featured images for the post in my theme

Currently I am using

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail')
```

and it worked fine with 1 images, but when i kept add new images the above code always retrieve the first image i attached to the post instead of the image i set as "featured"

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In you're theme functions.php file add

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );
```

Then in wp-admin when you edit a post you should have a featured image box where you can set 1 featured image . Then in the loop you can use the following functions :

```
the_post_thumbnail();
has_post_thumbnail();
```

---

Update

After you added post-thumbnails theme support , you **need** to set the featured image using the "featured image" box on the right sidebar on wp-admin/post.php page . It's right under the "post tags" box . Then outside the loop you can use get_the_post_thumbnail() function to retrive that image . If you didn't set any featured image for the post it will fetch the last image you inserted in that post .

One other way to set the featured image would be ( after you added post-thumbnail theme support ) , is when you insert an image into the post you will have a "set featured image" after you uploaded ( on the modal that let's you select image alignment ) . Then the image should be visible on the right sidebar "featured image" box .

Comment: yeah, i have done add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); but I am display the "feature images" out of wp loop, thats why i have been using get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail'), and it doesnt seem working

Comment: but , do you set the featured image using the "featured image" box on the right sidebar on post/edit wp-admin pages ? that picture doesn't have anything to do with the images you insert into posts , get_the_post_thumbail() should retrive that image only , and it works just well outside the loop .

Comment: yes, i did set the images as featured box. the problem is, it worked very well for the first image, but as soon as i put second /third images and set any later image as "featured image", the above code still display the initial featured image.

Comment: usualy you set 1 featured image per post , and that's how it's supposed to work . if you whant multiple featured images per post then i suggest you either find a pluggin or build one , or build theme function that runs a query straight on the database using `$wpdb` class .

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets the post's featured image URL, if not available then use given fallback url.
function get_featured_image_url($fallback_url) {
  if (is_front_page()) {
    return $fallback_url;
  }

  $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large');

  if (!$thumb) {
    return $fallback_url;
  }

  return $thumb[0];
}
```